# React Lazy Loading not showing Loading and showing all components at once

Tags: reactjs, loading

I'm trying to implement a placeholder animation much like what YouTube does. I'm using React Lazy and Suspense props to implement that. But lazy loading does not show loading and straight up loads components. I've tried to throttle my internet connection by network tab with no luck. I'm attaching my code. Thanks!

```
const Posts = lazy(() => import("./posts/posts"));
const Updates = lazy(() => import("../dashboard/updates/updates"));
const Navigation = lazy(() => import("../dashboard/navigation/navigation"));

function demoAsyncCall() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000));
}

class PinnedPosts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pinned_posts: true,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="pinned-posts">
        <div className="navigation">
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading..</div>}>
            <Navigation posts={this.state.pinned_posts}></Navigation>
          </Suspense>
        </div>
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading!</div>}>
          <div className="news">
            <h1 class="Pinned-post">Pinned Posts</h1>
            <Posts />
          </div>

        <div className="promotions">
          <h1 class="organization-update">Organization Updates</h1>
          <Updates></Updates>
        </div>
        </Suspense>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PinnedPosts;
```

Comment: Its better if you use rudex .Then you find everything . Try with componentWillReciveProps

Comment: Suspense does show a loader but not very often, this is because the components load very quickly in your App. Too fast to see the loader.

Comment: Hey @ShubhamKhatri thanks for replying, but I've seen people using lazy loading with suspense in which even a simple component with text was loading. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV9gvls8IP8)